# Run Work immediately before runnin periodic task - WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager, periodic-task

I want to run a periodic task as soon as a process ends, and then run a periodic daily task. I know how to run a periodic task, but my question is I need to run this periodic task immediately exactly once and after that regular periodic task should run on daily basis. Currently I need to wait for 1 day to execute the periodic task, How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is to use a `OneTimePeriodicWorker` that schedule your periodic Worker before returning `Result.success()`.

So, you enqueue the WorkRequest to run immediately:

```
val asSoonAsPossibleWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<InitialWorker>
                .addTag(TAG_OUTPUT)
                .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(asSoonAsPossibleWorkRequest)
```

and your Worker just enqueue the periodic Worker before returning `Result.success()`:

```
class InitialWorker(ctx: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(ctx, params) {

   override fun doWork(): Result {
       // Do Something Useful

       // Enqueue the periodic Worker
       val dailyWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<DailyWorker>(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
               .addTag(TAG_OUTPUT)
               .build()
       WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueue(dailyWorkRequest)

       return Result.success()
   }
}
```